# How to use the result of a mutation in other component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

I’m trying to wrap my head around apollo client.

I have a react native app. On one screen the user enters their first name and last name and a mutation is fired off to save this data. And the next screen is navigated to. On this screen I would like to access the first name. What is the best way to do this with apollo client? I haven’t found any good
examples of accessing query/mutation results in other components. Would I just read the cache? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: A mutation can (will) return data. In your case you could decide to return the first & last names as entered by the user, and pass them on as props to the screen you navigate to? Alternatively, you could just query the user's first name in your next screen, and rely on Apollo's cache to use the return value from your mutation to handle the query without firing it over the network. Note that for objects to be cached properly, they need an `id` property.

Comment: @Jaxx That makes sense. Thank you.